# Not enough space in File System

Tags: 11.10, wubi

Hi I'm a new Ubuntu user currently on 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot and I have problem with File System available space. I Installed it inside windows to another hdd I have. I have 2 disks 1 60GB SSD and 1 1TB common one partitioned in 2: 100GB for Ubuntu and the rest-other as storage.
Now when I go to Places "Computer" I can see a total of 4 disk references:
1.0TB Hard Disk E. Opening is my storage partition everything ok.
next are my 2 windows partitions on my SSD no problem with that either.
Finally File System Partition which reports the following thing upon properties click:
431,858 items, totalling 141.1 TB
(some contents unreadable)

this can't be since my partition that has Ubuntu is a fair 100GB space and this thing reads 141.1 TB which is insane. What's happening here?
Thanks in advance,
Therman

Answer (score 1):

Well, if a filesystem reports wrong amount of space used and some of its contents is unreadable it suggests a corrupted filesystem - possibly caused by your hard drive failing.

First of all, make sure you have a recent backup of all your important files. Then you can boot from an Ubuntu LiveCD and use `smartctl` to see S.M.A.R.T. status of your hard drive and run `fsck` to find/fix filesystem errors (provided that hardware is ok, otherwise it make no sense to fix them)